# .Net Core Garbage Collection When Running Many Instances On Same Machine On Linux

Tags: c#, .net, linux, .net-core, garbage-collection

My first StackOverflow question (after many years of reading through various threads).

I am having a particularly tough time resolving this issue, so any help is appreciated.

I am running many (50+) instances of a computationally expensive .Net Core on Linux.

The machine has enough cores (64 cores), and about ~500GB of RAM.

I have one simple method:

```
public static void Compute(Message m) {
// Does a lot of computation, memory allocation here
// All root objects are set to null at end (just to really make it clear!)
}
```

This method is called multiple times for each of the 50+ instances.

What I am finding is that the memory footprint of each process (in particular, VIRT using top) keeps increasing after each iteration. Eventually, each process attempts to reclaim memory, but still overall the available memory for the entire machine is precipitously low (<1-2%).  Finally, the GCs trigger, but the extremely low (sometimes 0%) available memory causes a lot of problems in my computation and several of the instances become "stuck" - basically halted and no longer performing any computations or listening to external events.

I've repeated this same experiment using fake code that just does number-crunching and large memory allocations, and I see the same pattern.

I've tried these things (separately, and together):

1. Creating a separate "reaper" thread that invokes GC.Collect(3,
   CollectionMode.Forced, true, true), etc.
2. Nullifying every temporary object in the computation and immediately invoking
   GC.Collect()
3. Reducing the number of instances dramatically

None of these worked, and I am rather stuck.

It appears that .Net is "holding on" to the memory unless absolutely, positively needed - but by then it is too late as all the other instances are also doing the same.  Eventually, this triggers a large GC by all the processes and then I end up with the dead/halting problem (some of the instances may be in the midst of launching a thread, or in a complex LINQ composition) and just silently die.

Technically, all of the created objects and temporaries have no roots, and should be marked as GC-able, but this doesn't happen smoothly and periodically as I would have liked.  Furthermore, the computation exists in an entirely different method, for which there is no state information that is saved at all in other objects.

Yet, the memory just keeps dropping and dropping until the available memory is extremely low.

If I had written this in C, I would have done a malloc/free and the memory would be reset after each iteration of the Compute() method.  Finally, I don't the issue is endemic to Linux, I observe the same behavior (for a single instance) on Windows as well.

Thank you for your suggestions in advance.

In reponse to some of the comments:
   1. I've tried every kind of GC.Collect() mode - forced, blocking, largeobject etc., gens 0-2 - some mild differences, but not anything that would lend comfort to a stable compute process
- 2) I've tried both workstation (starts off smaller - then reaches the same state) and server

Comment: Have you thought about implementing some object pooling technique? So you reuse object rather than throwing them away? Also which [GC mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/run-time-config/garbage-collector#flavors-of-garbage-collection) do you use?

Comment: Play around with `GCHeapCount` to make GC more aggressive. Now every of your 50+ instances is trying to consume everything (which means, A LOT of memory).

Comment: Did you enable [`gcServer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/run-time-config/garbage-collector#systemgcservercomplus_gcserver) option in config?

Comment: @GuruStron, object pooling is difficult - the objects are designed to be immutable.  And also, I've tried blocking, forced, largeobjectheap, server mode/client mode - all basically the same - with some mild differences.

Comment: @KonradKokosa - ok I'm going to try working with GCHeapCount - according to MSFT docs: "Limiting the number of heaps used for server GC is particularly useful for systems that run multiple instances of a server application." - which may be my situation.

Comment: @Ceremony also you can try to look at `GCHeapHardLimit` and `GCHeapHardLimitPercent` settings introduced in [.NET Core 3.0](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/pull/22180)

Comment: @KonradKokosa - very honored to have the author of "Pro .NET Memory Management" respond to my first question; thank you.

Comment: @GuruStron - wow there are many options there I didn't even notice.  I'll also try GCHardLimit, thank you for the pointer.

Comment: @GuruStron - you hit the nail on the head.  Totally solved all memory contention issues and also gave me a 2x computation performance increase.  I've posted this all in the answer.

Comment: @Ceremony, glad it helped!

Comment: Nice to hear you've solved your issue. Suggesting GCHard limits was my next step:)

Answer (score 1):

There were several suggestions that aimed to solved this problem - where multiple instances of a .Net Core 3.1 compute-heavy process on a 64-core ~500GB RAM Linux machine were each retaining their memory and refusing to relinquish until the bitter end (which created a whole lot of problems).

@Piotr suggested a thorough walkthrough of all the allocation - the most involved, but probably the most illuminating with respect to what is being created and retained.

@KonradKokosa suggesting working with the GCHeapCount runtime property of the GC.

@GuruStron suggesting toggling the GCHardLimit/GCHardLimitPercentage runtime property recently introduced in .Net Core 3.0.

@GuruStron's seemed the easiest to try first (you set a percentage of the total physical memory, and my understanding is that the GC will be invoked (not just for marking) when that threshold is reached.

This solution worked *PERFECTLY*.
I simply divided the maximum memory size by the expected max image size of the process, and used that to modify runtime.config.template to add the GCHardLimitPercentage = 3.5 parameter.

Not only did it completely solve the memory-retention issue, the compute process is now 100% faster (2x).

Absolutely wonderful, I spent the last week day and night working on this, but thanks to the solution.

I also urge others to look at the other solutions - I'm already behind in my project!

Thanks,
Ceremony

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't go "blindly" into this issue. Go with details. You just have to check, wherein detail is this memory being used. Is it only Gen1 that notice heavy usage. Or maybe there is some Gen3 - which you ware not aware of.

Playing with strings can create huge memory traffic. But you are saying, that the memory keeps lower and lower. And normally GC run would clear the memory almost totally if it would be only GEN1. As it keeps lowering with time - it suggest that there is some memory leak (it could be from one of the libraries you are using)

But of course, no one will tell you where and what it is without knowing details. And you are the only one, that can check the details.

You have to use some memory profiling application and check foryourself what is going on with the memory if you run it locally.

There are different memory profiling applications. Two of the most popular (both paid but both with trials) are:

https://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/

https://www.jetbrains.com/dotmemory/

You have to run the app, generate some "Traffic" in application and check where is the memory, and what kind of memory traffic you are dealing with (and from where)

This is the only thing, that could lead you to solution to your problem.

For now i can only say that this:

```
creating a separate "reaper" thread that invokes GC.Collect(3, CollectionMode.Forced, true, true), etc.
```

is not a good idea :) There are very few cases when you really want to be "smarter" that the GC algorithms and there are numerous cases when the developers use them and should not :) Instead of forcing the GC to do this job -simply make life "easier" for him, so that he will be almost unemployed ;)

Comment: Indeed I felt really ugly about the "reaper" thread but I was left with fewer options.  I have VS enterprise and also the ANTS mem profiler - I'll try those out.